# What is the best way to deal with toxic/unhelpful comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, comment-flags

Occasionally questions that I ask, especially those related to certain opinionated subjects, I get a rash of comments that can be most charitably described as 'unhelpful'.  I see these often when asking questions about the ColdFusion functions built off of the ext-js library.  These comments tend to take the form:

- Switch to JQuery
- Rethink your workflow
- You know using that functionality was a bad idea; what where you thinking?!

In many situations decisions are made by developers other than the questioner, or are made for reasons that would take far too long to explain in a simple SO question.  In either case, real world practicality makes those suggestions unrealistic regardless of how the questioner got to their current impasse.  These comments add nothing to the question, bury helpful responses (making SO a less efficient resource for others), and seem to exist purely to berate the questioner and create an unwelcoming environment.  This seems to be a recent development; I don't recall seeing this on SO in years past.

What is the best way to deal with these sorts of comments when asking a question?

---

I'm not trying to be difficult; I really wish to understand.

To clarify with an analogy, suppose someone goes to a car forum and posts a question about how to fix xyz on their 1992 Ford Explorer.  If another user posts "Buy a new Corvette", that response would be considered both unhelpful and insensitive.  The former because context is clear that for most people asking that question they simply could not afford a new Corvette.  The latter because there is a clear implication that the asker is somehow not living up to the commenter's standards.

In programming we have many similar situations.  Suppose you are working in a professional job with a system that many other people helped build, and may have existed before your time.  Your client calls and tells you there is a bug in a feature that they must access before close of business.  You work on it without success, and around 2:00 pm decide to post online to solicit help from others who may have more experience with this particular issue.  In this context, how is a comment encouraging you to embark on a half year project to switch frameworks helpful?

Similarly, what if the bug is occurring in a legacy system, or for a small business, that brings in barely a few thousand dollars per year.  Refactoring this system might require tens of thousands of dollars worth of work.  Is just fixing the bug in the existing code really "shooting yourself in the foot."  Would putting $20k into a product that will only ever make $10k in profit really the right decision?  Sarcastic responses like this are not just unhelpful, they are harmful.

My understanding is that SO was to be a place for professionals to help one another in a supportive and constructive atmosphere.  But I feel that the responses here are indicating that sarcastic, snarky, or otherwise insulting comments which do not contain enough information to be helpful are not just tolerated, but encouraged.  I wish to understand the reasoning for this.

Comment: The last one I would flag as not constructive. The other ones might warrant extension/elaboration but are not necessarily problematic in my opinion.

Comment: -0: Too little JQuery ;-)

Comment: Regarding your update. If your question is lending itself to such comments, then the background information that you have provided as an example would be necessary to add to the question.

Comment: I agree that sometimes people's tone could be a little less sharp on SO. You could try to head some comments off at the pass by explaining that you know some technology/algorithm is poor, but that you don't have time to fix it. However, it's worth noting that the best questions are the ones that are written generically (since they will be of most use to future readers). If you want to post at 2pm and get something by 6pm, it sounds a bit like the "Plz halp URGENT" questions we get, and they are closed for being too localised.

Comment: "sarcastic, snarky, or otherwise insulting comments ... are not just tolerated, but encouraged" - that's not my view, and not proven on the evidence presented. There _are_ snarky commenters on SO, but they can either be ignored or flagged. That moderation is available and working illustrates that there's a culture of removing unhelpful comments, imo.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work

Comment: People flag these sorts of comments.  The message usually makes its way to the intended recipient in time, though.

Comment: Moderation is certainly not working. Don't be dishonest.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You shouldn't be too selfish. Instead, always bear in mind that Stack Overflow is not your personal help desk but rather a knowledge base open to anyone.

Imagine some noob *enthusiast* comes across your question. Since they cannot tell good from bad due to lack of experience, they can take your exceptional case caused by desperate circumstances as a regular way of doing things. As it often happens. Thus, for such a case it is very handy to have a warning sign around - don't you think? Just don't take it as a personal comment, but as a comment on the case in general.

Comment: This answer discusses one of the very foundational principles of how the site works. I strongly agree with you!

Answer (score 24):

Telling people when they have an improperly designed system is *extremely* helpful, generally speaking.  Yes, sometimes the problems are beyond control, but many times they are not, or simply being aware of the problems/drawbacks of a design is useful information that can help keep the programmer's guard up.  It may also be useful to future readers who don't have the same constraints as the OP.

Just because *you* don't find a particular comment useful doesn't make it toxic or unhelpful.

Now yes, one should be constructive in indicating that there is a problem with someone's design.  You have provided examples of entirely constructive examples, however.  Telling someone, "you should rethink your workflow because [reasons]" is very constructive.

Your very last example is the only potentially concerning comment, and even that is an entirely constructive first half, with an unconstructive addition of "what where you thinking?!"  Removing that last bit (and presumably stating what is bad and why) turns it into a great comment.

Comment: Perhaps I should have used different wording, such as 'off topic'.  If a question is clearly about resolving an issue that a client likely needs complete by the end of the business day, how is a comment suggesting a year-long overhaul of a legacy system helpful?  I could understand if it were a blurb tacked on to an answer that addresses the actual question, but they often aren't.

Comment: @Nicholas Don't you worry too much. If a question is clearly about resolving an issue of shooting oneself in a leg, there is always a Good Samaritan around to help to pull the trigger. So, just a comment, telling not to do so, won't harm anyone *that* much.

Comment: @Nicholas If it's an answer, then that would not be an answer to the question.  As a comment, it is not intended to be an answer to the question.  It is there for potentially useful additional information that doesn't actually result in an answer to the question, which is exactly what this is.  This is exactly the type of information that comments are designed for.

Comment: No. If the person asking the question doesn't find your answer helpful, it isn't helpful. It's not up to you.

Comment: @srcs No, if the community thinks it's helpful, it's still helpful, it doesn't matter what the person who asked the question thinks.  It's not up to you.  If you're not interested in receiving useful information and just want someone to tell you what you want to hear, not matter how helpful it is, you can find people to do that.  That's not what this site is here for though.

Comment: Wrong. Only the person asking the question matters. Either answer the question exactly as it was asked or get off the site and stop ruining it for people who actually want to help.

Comment: @srcs how does an answer not being exactly what the OP was looking for ruin the site for "people who actually want to help"? Doesn't them answering literally show that they're wanting to help?

Comment: @srcs Wrong.  Everyone matters.  Either provide useful content that contributes to the community as a whole or get off the site and stop ruining it for people who actually want to help.

Comment: Wrong. Only the person asking the question matters. Don't reply to me again.

Comment: @srcs Wrong.  Everyone matters.  Please reply to me in a *constructive* and *helpful* manner in the future rather than simply being toxic and unhelpful.

Answer (score 6):

This is what you claim was said:

> You know using that functionality was a bad idea; what where you
>   thinking?!

This is what was actually said:

> It's interesting that you seem to know cfwindow is a poor approach to
>   addressing your needs, but you still went ahead and used it. I wonder
>   what the decision-maker was thinking here. Seriously.

On first sight, those two comments look virtually identical, but look a little deeper and you'll see that what was implied was a bit different. Here is the [actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187769/how-does-one-get-debugging-information-out-of-a-cfwindow) where that comment were posted.

The actual user didn't make any judgement call about cfwindow. In fact, the consensus seems to be that cfwindow usually works fine and that you should just have opened a new tab to view its results (as this is the canonical way of using cfwindow).

If you ask me (and I wasn't there to begin with), it's your vague explanation about there being too many variables and too many windows, and the fact that it's too complicated to explain, that prompted that original comment.

And no, I do not see that original comment as being "sarcastic, snarky, or otherwise insulting". I only see that original comment as a frustrated plea for trying to get more information out of you on your original problem (information which you provided, but mostly after that comment was posted).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a right way, it's entirely contextual. The best response may be to ignore and do nothing, ignore and flag, or simply state why you thought the answer was snarky and unhelpful. If you're about to make an angry response that adds nothing at all to the conversation then you might be better off just ignoring it instead.

I actually just did this [a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158747/is-normalizing-this-mysql-date-column-overkill) (in the comments on the question itself), I got an answer that came across to me as unpleasant and unhelpful and while my response was a little snarky I didn't go overboard and I basically just defended my position from what he said and told him why the comment didn't help me.

Apparently this worked because his response was a good one that went a long way toward answering my question.

Answer (score -6):

> This is what you claim was said:
>
> You know using that functionality was a bad idea; what where you thinking?!
>   This is what was actually said:
>
> It's interesting that you seem to know cfwindow is a poor approach to addressing your needs, but you still went ahead and used it. I wonder what the decision-maker was thinking here. Seriously.
>   On first sight, those two comments look virtually identical, but look a little deeper and you'll see that what was implied was a bit different.
>
> The actual user didn't make any judgement call about cfwindow...

Stephen, you may have misunderstood what Nicholas was saying.  He never indicated that the responder was commenting about cfwindow, specifically, but the decision making process itself.  The responder was asking him if he knew solution x was wrong, why did he choose it.  So essentially, yes, the actual and perceived response are the same in this case.

Dont forget, words dont convey the emotions behind them.  The responder very well could have meant:

"Wait, you knew this was a bad idea, yet you did it anyway?  Why, were the other options avail to you worse?"

Or did he mean, as Nicholas took it "You dummy!" lol

I did find the post was a little sarcastic, especially with him putting "seriously" at the end.  That really wasn't needed.

On the converse, the responder may have meant "seriously" in a sincere and not sarcastic but in a "help me understand" or "This is a teaching moment" sort of way.

However, he is asking for help, and would have appreciated to forgo the lecture / question and get right to what you said - to open another tab and see the results.

But yes, Nicholas should have provided more detail in his original post.

I dont think either party is at fault, we all read into posts incorrectly or sometimes do not put enough info in our first post.

To Nicholas's question on how to handle - I have gotten unhelpful posts and I simply just skip over them.

Comment: This appears to be a response to another answer. That's not what answers are for. They should answer the question. If you want to comment on another answer, wait until you have the rep to do so, then comment on it.

Comment: And FYI, to echo what @MikeMcCaughan said, the downvotes you are getting are simply signifying that this post is a 99% just a reply and hence not useful.  Even on Meta, Stack Overflow is not a traditional forum.

Comment: Mike, are you a moderator?

Comment: Sorry, you didn't @ me, so I just saw this. I'm not an elected moderator (moderators have the diamonds next to their names; employees too); I just care about the quality of the site, and helping others to use the site in a manner most useful to others.

Comment: Then you should solicit the help of a moderator, and let them enforce the policies.

Comment: You should refrain from telling other people what to do, you busybody hall monitor cunt.