# Dealing with patronizing answers (which assume you're asking the wrong question)

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Sometimes I ask questions about fairly obscure topics (details of compiler, proprocessor behavior..., ways of using lesser known language features). *(C/Python mostly though I'm not sure it matters)*.

I wouldn't be so presumptuous to call myself an expert but have been developing for ~10 years in one way or another,
so by the time it comes to asking a question which hasn't already been asked *(as far as I can see from searching on SE and other resources)* it's usually relating to some corner case.

The problem I find is that I get answers directed at some inexperienced developer, who doesn't know of alternatives: which **are** probably better in most situations.

---

Here are some examples...

> If you want feature ****, C++ is really what you're after. In C++ you can...

*...ignoring that the question is about **** language (and the code-base is well established and not about to jump-ship based on a single language feature).*

> (Readability > Performance), code is read more than it's written, so you shouldn't try to...

*...ignoring that some code is generated at build-time, runs in a tight loop, on embedded systems, GPU...etc. or that less readable code is an acceptable tradeoff in some situations.*

> Of course disk access is going to be your real bottleneck, so you should...

*...assuming you're not writing CPU intensive code.*

> If your customer is willing to pay for it...

*...assuming you're developing for a customer who pays some hourly rate.*

> early optimization is the root of all evil, first you should try...

*...right, it's important to remember this, profile production work-loads. etc...*

> Why would you write that? You should change your code to...

*...assuming I'm asking the question about code I wrote, rather than a 3rd party library I'm reviewing/auditing.*

---

These kinds of answers often miss the point of the question and give some quick solution I'm already aware of,
They may be helpful to varying degrees but avoid the question.

I rather not down-vote them since the authors are genuinely trying to help, but they tend to gloss over the question and parrot some *"conventional wisdom"*.

What is a good way to handle answers like this?

Comment: With 10 years of experience, you should probably be able to *anticipate* those answers - if you know that you're asking something which falls outside conventional wisdom, explain that in the question: "I know this solution X is more readable, but I've benchmarked my application and I know that this is in the CPU-critical path, so I'm really looking for efficiency even at the cost of readability at this point."

Comment: Sure, I do anticipate the answers and attempt to be clear... but there seems to be an assumption that something obscure is almost certainly asking the wrong question, I feel like saying *"Please answer the question I asked, not the one you think I asked"*... but it sounds very rude/irate/entitled, which I why I asked the question here...

Comment: The site does operate with the strong assumption that information and advice is not insulting, whatever it looks like.  If you get too much of it then, perhaps, you asked too many people.  Selective tagging is pretty important.

Comment: Yes, I give people the benifit of doubt and dont act offended, afterall they are trying to help - Somtimes the answer is **"No, you cant do that"** and there is an inclination to give _some_ positive answer, even if its only vaguely related to the original question. When a better answer may be - **"Thats simply not supported"**

Comment: @gnat: Do you know *every* meta-question by heart?

Comment: @Deduplicator nope. Search for duplicates begins when I think "it can't be that nobody asked this before" :)

Comment: @ideasman42 It's a shame this happens really. I've had the same experience, and ended up with my question downvoted and the patronizing answers upvoted. I think it comes from the flood of newbies to the site, who always assume you know far less than them.

Comment: see also: [What is the best way to deal with toxic/unhelpful comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260396/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-toxic-unhelpful-comments)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An approach that has always worked for me is -

- leaving a polite comment that makes clear that this is not what you're looking for, and list reasons. Hinting that you're a very experienced developer also helps.
- if necessary, editing the question to make clear that the answer's approach isn't what you're looking for. I like to make it clear it's an edit so people see I'm aware of the existing answers, and that the issue is still open.

Comment: I know this Q/A is old but I wanted to add my two cents in *rejection* of this answer. I wrote a question that was much like the OP asking for help optimizing an algorithm. I listed 5 steps of a process, then stated clearly I only wanted help with steps #2 through #4 which were CPU intensive. Despite this I got answers focusing on steps #1 & #5 which dealt with pre/post file I/O. Time and again I repeated in comments I needed help with the CPU steps and yet nearly everyone focused on the file I/O, some going so far as to tell me I was wasting time asking the question.

Comment: Your point being?

Comment: My point being that some users will not carefully read the question, or if they do they will opt to ignore all efforts to inform them of any paradigm for the answer before and after the question is asked. Is your answer the best answer, probably under the current situation it is but it is not a **solution** to the root problem that we have no adequate means to correct the behavior of SO users who (as the OP said) *provide patronizing-answers-which-assume-youre-asking-the-wrong-question*. We need a way to enforce the idea of *answer the question that was asked* and show some modicum of respect.

Comment: That's a common sentiment among folks who had a bad experience on Stack Overflow, and it's understandable. Enforcing the things you want would not likely be a good idea for the place as a whole, though. We already have fine tools in place for ensuring both "answering the question" and respectful discourse. Your question was a very, very borderline case in a system with a very narrow scope... maybe the real answer here is that that kind of question just doesn't work well here. I've had plenty of questions in my career that I refrained from asking here for the same reason, and researched myself.

Comment: I also asked a meta question which led to this meta as a related/duplicate of mine. From there it seems there are a chain of related/duplicate questions on this issue going back years. The bottom line is it is rude & unprofessional to dismiss an actual question and tell a person they do not know what they are asking. There are many examples. Case-in-point: Today on our EL&U forum an OP was told point blank ["the phrase ... simply doesn't exist ... **you misheard**"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323803). This is a long-term and toxic (sub)culture in SO (& SE in general).

Comment: Maybe. Yet, most "solutions" to the problem brought up in the heat of the moment by people who had just had a bad experience on the site generally tend to be awful. There is no easy fix to the fact that some individuals are curt or even rude (even when asking a fair question like whether the OP misheard something), or appear rude through the Internet where you don't have voice, facial expressions, etc. Generally, it also seems that highly technically talented people aren't always the most socially talented. It's a much discussed issue here on Meta. What exactly do you want to do about it?

Comment: "**What exactly do you want to do about it?**" -- ah now *THAT* is a good question! For now I do not know the answer but I wish that the question would be well discussed and options proposed. On a gut level (heat-of-the-moment to use your phrase) I think maybe having another sub-option for "disregards the question asked" under the *flag* feature could be one solution but we also would need some consensus on when to use that flag. Perhaps instead of suppressing comments flagged with this sub-option, they could be displayed in a colored background to show them as being inappropriate answers.

Comment: @O.M.Y.  comments that are completely unrelated to the question asked can be flagged as "too chatty" and have a high chance of being removed. As to comments that simply *disagree* with the OP.... they can be valuable. Very, very often, askers *need* to be told that they are completely wrong. It's happened to myself, and it's one of the most educational experiences you can have here. We already disallow answers that don't answer the question; adding similar restrictions to the comments system would be super counterproductive.

Answer (score 6):

You know, part of your problem is probably *not downvoting bad answers*.

Immediate feedback, which involves commenting *as well as voting*, is critical to not letting such answers overwhelm your question.

Another part might be not making sure the question is completely clear as to the requirements, which should include your level of knowledge in that area, and specifics as to why all those things you acknowledge here as generally good are *not helpful*.

You should do so at least with edits, if you didn't before or with enough emphasis. People are understandably sceptical of any claim of expertise which is not shored up by demonstrating it.

Comment: Yep, I do edits if the answers show some part is unclear, and I do downvote bad answers, although normally when they're obviously wrong/misleading. For answers that miss-the-point of the question, I've found its good to wait a bit before down-voting, sometimes they're edited and improved within the first day or 2.

Comment: I guess those improvements only follow due to commenting to the author. And sure, sometimes one has to wait a bit for any action to have a result. By the way, your question here should be quite a common meta-question.

Comment: I've had the same problem as the OP. When I downvoted bad answers in the past, they get upvoted many times instead by people who haven't read the question in it's entirety. It's an interesting proposal but I don't think it always helps.