# Is Andrew Barber no longer a moderator?

Tags: support, moderators

I read an old [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260396/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-toxic-unhelpful-comments?answertab=active#comment42174_260399) by Andrew Barber, and noticed that there is no diamond next to his name. Is he no longer a moderator?

His [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) still mentions:

> [Community Moderator ♦ on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) (AKA Evil Unicorn Overlord)

but the link does not include him.

Comment: His last tweet and last time seen on SO is also February 3... I hope he's alright.

Comment: I think any speculation as to reasons is uncool, but the lack of a diamond on his profile now clearly indicates that he is no, at this moment, a moderator.

Comment: I know your question is really about a specific person, but for anyone else who happens across this and doesn't know, there's a page that lists [current moderators](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic (and answered) because the answer is clear: Andrew Barber is not currently a moderator. Having this question open and available seems counter-productive to me and unhelpful to anyone.

Comment: For the record: I know the "historical significance" lock reason doesn't quite fit, but it's marginally better than the other options.

Comment: If anyone wishes to get in touch with us about this, [please contact us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) (and at your option, link to my comment for increased expediency!)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Andrew hadn't accessed his account in over two months, which is pretty unusual for an SO mod.

We reached out to him, but haven't been able to connect with him, so we've removed his diamond until we can determine what's up.

Comment: Let's all hope it's nothing bad. Or that it at least gets better soon.

Comment: That doesn't sound good :( I echo what @Deduplicator says.

Comment: *"until we can determine what's up"* ... this is exactly what will antagonize the situation.

Comment: @Kermit As far as his status goes, it's a question of when he might be able to return to the site. Us holding out hope that things will return to normal, _as we do when any moderator goes quiet_ is hardly antagonistic or provocative, it's just what normally happens in situations where we remove someone's access due to inactivity.