# The description in "Who are the moderators?" is misleading

Tags: bug, user-interface, moderators, description

If you click on "Users" and then "Moderators", you get this (the screenshot is from TeX.SE, but it's the same elsewhere):

[image]

Where I read "we periodically hold democratic moderator elections."

Since, as far as I know, moderators are elected for life, I think you should change that sentence, because it is misleading when it says *periodically*.

I understand *periodically* as *every n years*, and I think it should be more correct to write *when needed*.

Comment: Cross site duplicate / related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297488/disinformation-on-moderator-elections

Comment: I agree that the wording is misleading, TeX.SE is a good example because that site exists since 2010 and it did not have an election since 2011.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you, yes, I took TeX.SE just to show that "periodically," in that case, is completely wrong.

Comment: @rene I think I asked on the wrong site, is it possible to move my question on Meta SE?

Comment: "democratic" might also be a bit misleading given that it seems to be impossible to trigger a new election from within the user base https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8205/do-we-need-more-moderators

Comment: There are two English sites you can ask for meaning of "periodically" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/periodically has both "at regular intervals of time" and "from time to time")... I personally feel it close to "occasionally" and not "regularly".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Even if "periodically" can mean under some special circumstances "from time to time", in this context it does not. Rather, in this context "we periodically hold democratic moderator elections." really has the message this happens more than once (per site, of course).

Answer (score 5):

Moderators can and do step down and some have died. That they are elected for life does not therefore absent the need for periodic elections.

Sites can also grow in popularity, with more users, questions and answers to moderate, more moderators may be required even if all the existing moderators remain.

Comment: I'm not an English mother tongue, in Italian "periodically" means "every x years" (or, in general, "every x period of time"). I think the word should be substituted by "when needed".

Comment: Between "step down" and "have died" you can add "get fired" and "go missing in action" ...

Comment: @CarLaTeX It means it happens repeatedly. Colloquially English does not require a fixed duration to use periodically although mathematicians would disagree, in a similar way to their disagreement with with the definition of the word "theory"

Comment: @RobertLongson Also "repeatedly" in Italian means "more than one time", and I would not use it for an election for life.

Comment: The election happens more than one time. Each moderator is only elected once though.

Comment: @RobertLongson even if there is a meaning of "periodically" that covers current practise (i.e., elections are held when the need arises, possibly never when the need never arises) then the wording is still confusing, because "periodically" is understood by many people as "in fixed intervals", especially in the context of elections. The wording could be improved to reduce the confusion.

Comment: @rene I am trying to envision what "go missing in action" means, but I am stuck...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar "Missing in action": Stop coming to the site without any announcement, don't react to e-mails, etc. No one knows why they're gone, they're just gone.

Comment: Who died? Did I miss an announcement?

Comment: @CodyGray *I died a thousands times* but I'm not a mod so it can't be me ...

Comment: @CindyMeister "Missing in action" probably refers to cases like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290286/10957435)