# What to do in case a user is spreading negativity, instead of answering the question

Tags: discussion

Few users, who lack the foresightedness or the one who doesn't understand the question start talking nonsense. Just wanted to know, if some one is discouraging or preventing your question from being answered, even if it's a valid question. How should we go about it?

Comment: Please be more specific. Perhaps they are only trying to help? You don't *have* to respond to comments, you can either ignore them or flag them for a moderator to clean up.

Comment: Are we talking about your most recent question? You are free to ignore the specific feedback given there.

Comment: related (possible duplicate): [What is the best way to deal with toxic/unhelpful comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260396/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-toxic-unhelpful-comments)

Comment: The user who left those comments on your most recent question is known to us. I've removed them. In the future, if you encounter other rudeness like this, flag the rude comments and we'll review them. We can clean them up and have a conversation with the user responsible afterward.

Comment: @Brad Larson edited the description, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to say given your question here is pretty vague and doesn't link to any content for us to evaluate.

Essentially, you have the tools the site gives you:

1. Downvote
2. Flag
3. Comment explaining why their actions are bad
4. Don't do anything -  because we all have our own rights and opinions
   to comment and state things. Perhaps there is something they know
   which you do not?

Which one is relevant depends on the scenario, which we do not know.