# What's our policy on people who, instead of answering, question a user's reasoning for asking?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, scope

I see this *all the time*, where a user will ask a question, but many of the comments and answers are actively trying to question the user's methodology. It's a bit hard to explain, so I'll try again:

> If I don't use Emacs, don't repetitively explain how it would be "easier" if I did. All I wanted to know was {something totally unrelated to Emacs}.

[An example](https://superuser.com/a/213458) where a user is asking about one program, but another is recommended. The question clearly asks for a remote file system that can mount on their local fs, but the answer does not provide this and is clearly changing the subject from sshfs.

And also this type of criticism:

> "I don't think Python is the fastest language for that, use C++" "But I want to use Python"

I know, sometimes this is useful, but *most of the time* it's annoying and counterproductive, yet these comments and answers remain put.

Is there an official policy on this? Also, sorry if this is a dupe, it's a hard thing to search for.

Related, though I'm not sure how close:

[What is the best way to deal with toxic/unhelpful comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260396/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-toxic-unhelpful-comments?lq=1)

[What to do in case a user is spreading negativity, instead of answering the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302626/what-to-do-in-case-a-user-is-spreading-negativity-instead-of-answering-the-ques)

Comment: Well, many people ask for XY problems, so that kind of criticism is oftenly justified. No _official policy_ that I'm aware of. If you really think the comment is not constructive, flag it as such.

Comment: Questioning a user's methodology != spreading negativity. Most of the time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The X/Y problem is different. I know what I want, but the other users try to change that view.

Comment: The *examples* you gave, without any of the neccessary context to understand, paint the commenters as a bit deranged. That's a bit unlikely, but there are all types, it's a big world. Handle it like @πάνταῥεῖ recommended.

Comment: @TheDoctor You should give us some more concrete examples (as links for such comments you have found) please. As asked, you don't give us enough context to judge.

Comment: Well, that answer *on SU* gives an alternative solution to the problem. What's the matter about it?

Comment: Asking about policy? [You should totally drop that & try jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492).

Comment: Often, it's a kind way of saying 'your requirement is clearly insane and no design/implementation has an hope of working at all'.

Comment: Seeing the examples, basically we're talking about fanboyism here right? People promoting the technology they've latched themselves onto and think everyone should be using. Some are more sneaky than others and will do it in the form of "I don't know how you would do it in Python, but if you were using <whatever other tech that is not tagged> you would do it like THIS...". If so: those answers/comments are off-topic, plain and simple.

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes offering an alternative approach is perfectly valid, as in:

> Q: I've put square wheels on my vehicle, but now it doesn't roll very
>   well... How can I fix it?
>
> A: Use round wheels instead...

I get the feeling that this isn't the case you're asking about though...

In cases where you're asking about a very specific piece of tech, whether it be a library, a language, or what have you, it helps to be very specific about why you're using that tech.

If you suspect that someone will come along and point out that you wouldn't have that problem using some other tech, then take a moment to explain why you've chosen the tech you have, or why you're stuck with a less than optimal tech.

On the other hand, if you suspect that someone is littering the site with answers that don't really answer the question, or that they're simply expressing a personal preference for a specific tech, feel free to downvote.

---

Here's one of my old answers to a similar issue:
[Is it OK to suggest the OP change his approach in order to offer a new answer to the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179567/217863)

Comment: +1 for the fishing analogy, that's truly brilliant ;)

Comment: Recently, in the real world, I came across a perfect example of this. A friend of mine asked a professor how he could do something in C#, and the professor said, "Don't use C#, use Scipy, it's got this great builtin..." and went on for a minute or two about how useful it was before my friend could mention that he *had* to use C# for a class, so Scipy was out of the question. It's not always the XY problem or a wrong tech problem; there are requirements which go over what would be theoretically best.