# Is it okay to discourage someone from using a platform

Tags: discussion, answers

<strike>And to clearify why I think this is not a duplicte, is that I'm not asking about an answer Y on a question X, I'm asking if it is okay to discourage an asker to use a certain platform?</strike>

And for me, to recommend/advice another platform, bringin up its advantages, would be prefectly okay though.

I ran into this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33461630/2827823.

At first the answerer answered the question, then, after a comment from the OP, he added this to the answer:

> Another simple solution is **don't use blogger**. I used it initially but
>   stopped it because of these reasons only. With Blogger, you can't get
>   enough customization and you are under "Google" and dependent on that.
>   If you want to make your blog unique, a much better alternative is to
>   use WordPress which is open source, independent and has more
>   customization.
>
> Though it will be difficult for you to move from blogger to word press
>   but it will help in future. Bloggers/blogspots were used initially but
>   now technology has moved and we have much better alternative. The
>   future of blogger will be dark as everyone is now moving to Word Press
>   (which enjoys the open-source brand). Check this out

Is this part okay to be left as is?

The action I planned to take was:

1. Ask the answerer to remove that part.
2. If not removed, rollback the answer and comment that it adds maybe a little too much "noise".

But then I was thinking, should I?

---

A related question (thanks to apaul34208):

- [What's our policy on people who, instead of answering, question a user's reasoning for asking?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307708/whats-our-policy-on-people-who-in-stead-of-answering-question-a-users-reason)

Comment: This is a total dupe.  When you ask Y, and I say "no, do X", I am *discouraging* Y.  Whatever Y is doesn't matter.  We don't need a question about discouraging platforms, discouraging frameworks, discouraging languages, discouraging source control servers, discouraging blah blah friken blah.

Comment: No, I'm specifically discouraging Y.  I do this because X is preferrable.  It has one extra segment, and so is therefore superior in every way to Y.  If I wasn't discouraging Y, then Y did I not just find a way to make Y work?

Comment: By the power of greyskull, obviously.  That and logic.  And we is everybody.  They elected me to talk for them.  They also want me to tell you to send me all your cash.  Any more questions?

Comment: Paypal, preferably.

Comment: There is a tag for [tag:blogger].  If this is relevant for an answer to be correct, it should be edited into the question **and** the tag should be applied.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307708/whats-our-policy-on-people-who-in-stead-of-answering-question-a-users-reason

Comment: @Will My comments were an attempt to try make you see what I was trying to say and as I seemed to fail doing so, they no longer add any value to my question and therefore removed. Thanks to the dialog itself, I did a minor update though, to try to be more clear with my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question and answer are disjointed for me.  The question asks a generic, run-of-the-mill CSS question, with no immediately identifying characteristics that it's even *related* to Blogger.  With that in mind, I'm not confident that *any* of the answers are complete, since the OP elected to introduce this new information into a comment which could up and disappear on a whim.

In this scenario, I'd ask the OP to clarify since one of the answers hinges on a remark they made there.  I wouldn't take action on the answer yet, since I can't be certain that its advice is relevant or not.

In general, though, my preference is to not discourage someone from using a platform unless there is an *absolute* prohibition on the coding action they want to take.  I believe that Blogger is a restrictive platform in that right, but I wouldn't want to tell someone to move over platforms over something as simple as *that*.