# Are comments productive to ask why the OP is opting for a particular way?

Tags: discussion

Is it productive for developers to ask why someone would do something in a particular way rather than answer a question as asked?

Wouldn't it be less condescending to save such comments for after the question has been answered first?

There may be a perfectly good reason why a particular developer wishes to proceed in a specific way. Forcing them to explain it without providing an answer to their question seems presumptuous and rude.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Glorfindel:  It's related but I don't see it as a dupe.

Comment: Quick question: if i see someone holding a gun to his foot and asking me how to shoot, should i not ask why first?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not even mad about this question.  Not sure why it is worthy of downvotes.

Comment: @Makoto Same here.  Not sure why it has all of the down votes.

Comment: @makoto well the question is extremely condescending, presumptive, entitled, and rude.  I suspect that has something to do with it.

Comment: @Servy:  I can forgive that much.  The user has come here in a huff and is frustrated with why they're getting so much blowback from asking a question when they're trying to phrase it in a specific way.  I don't see how what they're asking is terrible though.

Comment: @makoto it's not *what* they asked so much as *how* it was asked.  That, and this is a common enough question, so there's a lack of research.

Comment: @rene:  I'll edit that in a  bit later then.  It'll take some of the edge off.

Comment: @gnat:  I see that question as related but not strictly a dupe.

Comment: @rene how about, ["What is the best way to deal with toxic/unhelpful comments?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260396/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-toxic-unhelpful-comments) :)

Comment: Mark, are you proposing "downvote as unclear and move on" approach? Without comments to clarify question it is usually very hard to provide appropriate answer.

Comment: @Patrice 'someone holding a gun to his foot and asking me how to shoot, should i not ask why first?', not on SO. Here, you make sure they have a round in the chamber and the safety is off.

Comment: Software development is often about spotting different approaches that are easier to write, easier to debug or actually avoid huge chunks of crap altogether.  If the OP has some contraint that forces the use of a screwdriver to drive nails, then they should say so in the question to avoid 'you are a total moron - use a hammer' comments/answers.

Comment: Make sure you press the muzzle to your foot, you'd be surprised how much you flinch when pulling the trigger while pointing the gun at yourself.

Comment: To continue with the gun metaphors, what's with the 'Forcing them to explain'?  I'm not holding a gun to their heads - they can simply not reply to such comments, and so receive no further free help from  contributors who are dumb enough to donate spare time to SO and have to deal with such disrespect from such entitled thugs.  I strongly suspect that most such thugs are deadbeat students whose profs have issued contraints that are unreasonable outside the madcademic community.  Stuff 'em, if they don't like the help on SO, they can go pay for it elsewhere.

Comment: "Stuff 'em, if they don't like the help on SO". Why should "they" like it when it isn't help. It isn't rocket science. Either you know an answer or you don't. If you were interested in being helpful instead of caressing your own ego you would provide the information asked for. There would be nothing wrong with suggesting a better approach once you've done so. In the meantime, you are assuming you know why they want the information when you may not, the epitome of arrogance.

Comment: @Mark but the intent of stack was always to create a repository of knowledge for future visitors. I prefer to make sure these future visittors understand CLEARLY the risk associated with what they are implementing. Remember: your question should be useful to ALL future visitors with similar questions. Isn't it important to make sure there is a disclaimer for THESE users? No matter what YOU are asking for? Not arrogance, just forward thinking about your question when you won't care about it anymore

Comment: This is not a duplicate... wtf

Answer (score 22):

> Forcing them to explain it without providing an answer to their question seems presumptuous and rude.

Don't take it personally, but a developer should always be prepared to justify an approach to a solution.  Not necessarily just because of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but also due to the fact that, if you want help from outside sources, those outside sources also need to be on the same page.

Answer (score 18):

I am fully prepared to answer questions directly and exactly as asked, with no condescension, presumption or any posssible perceived rudeness.  I agree that posters often want exact answers to their questions without speculation or deviations.

I charge €65 per hour, minimum 4 hours, plus any unusual expenses incurred, (eg. for site visits). An up-front non-returnable fee of €250 applies to contracts shorter than one week.

PayPal would be OK for short contracts.  Obviously, such posters will need to pay up front, day-by-day.

For free, you may well be asked if you really need to explicitly terminate all your worker threads before exiting your app, and all the other stuff, whether you want it or not, and I would expect answers, not moaning on meta.

Take your choice.

Answer (score 12):

> Is it productive for developers to ask why someone would do something
>   in a particular way rather than answer a question as asked?

Absolutely. I've seen several posts where the OP wants something to be done and is quite clear about the end result but chooses the wrong (less efficient / bad ) approach to achieve it. By asking the OP why he / she is doing something in a particular way, we can easily suggest better approaches or agree that the OP is doing the right thing.